# How to insert the name of the functions in the location of the SHAP Values ForcePlot?

Tags: python, machine-learning, shap

I am using the Machine learning SHAP values library, for interpreting ML models, when I do ForcePlot it is not returning the name of the features, but the respective value of that feature.

Is there a parameter that I should change? (when I used it, it perfectly plotted the name of the features)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're missing the `feature_names` argument. Feed it with a list of the respective feature names, and you should get the corresponding feature name beneath each value.

In the case of having a dataframe, it infers the feature names from the columns, but it seems that in your case you have an array.